# When firefox is running, some of the characters won't work

Tags: keyboard, firefox

When im running firefox some of my characters that uses the shift key won't work.

Can anyone help me to understand how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

```
lsb_release -cd; setxkbmap -v -query; env | grep -e 'LANG' -e 'LC_'
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Codename:   focal
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+br(thinkpad)+us:2+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     br,us
variant:    thinkpad,
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Would you add output of `lsb_release -cd; setxkbmap -v -query; env | grep -e 'LANG' -e 'LC_'`  also Do you face this only with Firefox?

Comment: And yes, it happens when firefox is being used only

Comment: Edited and done

Comment: Test if every thing right on system side, using `xev` in terminal. Then test Firefox in Safe Mode, Go in Its menu: Help and select Restart with Add-ons Disabled ... See if it is the same thing

Comment: i've tried the procedure above, and it's presenting the same problem, when i turn off the browser the keys return to work properly, so it's something related to the browser, now what it is i don't know, need some help to fix it.

Comment: It's just the shift key, with of without the browser on, it stops working and starts again when it wishes so ...... both, left and right shifts !